# jquery qtip on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

I'm messing around with the jquery "qtip" tooltip plugin and i'm trying to add the qtip functionality to elements that are dynamically added to my webpage(via ajax) but can't figure out how. I think i need to use "live" in my jquery somewhere but don't know where.

Any help would be great.

Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/888ap/1/) with my dilemma. You'll notice the qtip works great on the three existing links but if you click "Add Link" then hover over the created link, there is no tooltip even though it has the "qtip" css class.

The javascript box contains a function to add a link to a box dynamically, the qtip plugin, then my custom code that creates the qtip with all elements with the "qtip" css class at the end.

the following is my jquery ajax code. I don't know how to reapply the qtips to the new elements with the qtip class.

```
function ajaxunitCalendar(X,Y,Z){

    $('#ajaxdiv').fadeOut(300,loadcontent); 

    function loadcontent()
    {
        var changecal = "<?php echo base_url();?>calendar/unit/" + X + "/" + Y + "/" + Z + " #ajax_calendar_wrap";
        $("#ajaxdiv").load(changecal,'',function(){
        $('#ajaxdiv').fadeIn(300); 

            return false; 
        });

        return false;
    }

        return false;   
};
```

Comment: You're going to have to re-apply the plugin every time you add another link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, completely misread that...too late at night :P

This is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/navgarcha/888ap/3/

Just apply the `qtip()` plugin to all the elements you create.

Comment: hmm...that doesn't seem to do it. The links created in the box still don't have tooltips.

Comment: awesome. How would i go about adding the qtip functionality to html loaded from jquery's ajax? For instance, if the "Add Link" link loaded 3 links with the qtip class from another webpage inside of #box? Is there a way to add the qtips to existing and all future instances of the .qtip class no matter if they're created solely from js or loaded into the dom with ajax?

Comment: You will have to reapply the plugin on the htmlresponse (find the correct anchor links first) within the `onSuccess` callback

Comment: alright thanks. Anyway you could like at my updated original post and help me do that with the code i have there?

Comment: @David Try `$('#ajaxdiv').find('a.qtip').qtip(qtipConfig);` inside your callback function

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the QTip after you append the element as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/888ap/4/

and this code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add_link").live('click', function(e) {


            $('#box').append("<a href='#' class='qtip'>Another Link</a><br/><br/>");
            e.preventDefault();
            bindQtip();
        });
        bindQtip();
    });

function bindQtip() {
    $(".qtip").qtip({
        content: 'Hello!',
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topRight',
                tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            }
        },
        style: {
            padding: 10,
            textAlign: 'center',
            border: {
                width: 1,
                radius: 3
                //color: '#8ACAED'
            },
            tip: 'bottomLeft',
            name: 'red' // Inherit t
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly efficient as you would be reapplying the qtip plugin to all that match the class each time you add a new link, when we have the only one we want to apply it to already defined and accessible.

Comment: Narrow down the selection to the newly appended element.  Live is not going to help you with this one, it is used to append FUNCTIONS to EVENTS.  You need an event to trigger some code that appends the QTIP.  In my opinion the most logical place to append the qtip is when the #add_link is clicked.